# How to add firestore credentials in Python outside of GCP

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to follow the instructions [here:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python).

The line I am having difficulty with is:

`cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccount.json')`

Firstly, I would prefer to add the credentials from environment variables rather than a file but I don't see a way to do that in Python.

Failing that, I would like to use a relative path to the file but I can't figure out what the relative path should be!

Should I rather be putting the file somewhere in the root of the (Linux) host so that it will always be found in the same place regardless of which environment the app runs in? If so, what is the 'correct' place to store it?

Comment: Provide the credentials to the Python client library. You can either pass the credentials as a path to a file or directly as a dictionary. You can use the `google.oauth2.service_account` module to load your credentials from a JSON file. It's a good practice to store the credentials file in a secure location and not in the root of the machine. You can use a relative path to the file if it is located in the same directory as your Python script. Also load the credentials from environment variables, and create the credentials object using the `from_service_account_info()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass the credentials as a dictionary which solved my problem.

For me the documentation was not clear, so in case it helps someone else,based on @Chanpols comment above, you can replace:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccount.json')
```

with:

```
dict = {...} #content of serviceAccount.json
cred = credentials.Certificate(dict)
```